# Refer variable from different class

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace Matrix_Algebra
{
    public struct S_Matrix_size
    {
        public int size_R, size_C;
        public S_Matrix_size(int r, int c)
        {
            this.size_R = r;
            this.size_C = c;
        }
    }

    public class C_Matrix_entries
    {

        public C_Matrix_entries()
        {
            int r, c;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter number of rows and columns ");

            r = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            S_Matrix_size size = new S_Matrix_size(r,c);

            double[,] entry = new double [size.size_R,size.size_C];

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the entries from first row [left to right] to the last row ");
            for (int i = 0; i<size.size_R; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the {0} row", i + 1);
                for (int j = 0; j<size.size_C;j++)
                {
                    entry[i, j] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                }
            }       
        }    


    }
}

namespace Row_Reduce_Algebra
{
    using Matrix_Algebra;
    public class TEST
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            C_Matrix_entries matrix_no1 = new C_Matrix_entries();
            for (int i = 0; i < **matrix_no1.size**; i++)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

As the title says, I'm trying to access a variable from a class instance, but don't know how to do it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @GrantWinney rightfully pointed out (as I was shaping up a working reply for you), you cannot access `matrix_no1.size` because it is inaccessible.  (It is also out of scope being that `matrix_no1` is a local variable declared in the default `C_Matrix_entries` constructor.)

Based on your code, here is an end-to-end working example of how to fix the problem using a somewhat different public property added to `C_Matrix_entries`.  Beyond the flavor of the new `S_Matrix_size` public property you add to `C_Matrix_entries` (i.e. Grant Winney's will work too), you will need to compute the product of its `size_R` and `size_C` properties in your loop's setup.

```
using System;

namespace Matrix_Algebra
{
    public struct S_Matrix_size
    {
        public int size_R, size_C;
        public S_Matrix_size(int r, int c)
        {
            this.size_R = r;
            this.size_C = c;
        }
    }

    public class C_Matrix_entries
    {
        private S_Matrix_size _size;

        public C_Matrix_entries()
        {
            int r, c;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter number of rows and columns ");

            r = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            _size = new S_Matrix_size(r,c);

            double[,] entry = new double [_size.size_R,_size.size_C];

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the entries from first row [left to right] to the last row ");
            for (int i = 0; i<_size.size_R; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the {0} row", i + 1);
                for (int j = 0; j<_size.size_C;j++)
                {
                    entry[i, j] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                }
            }       
        }    

        public S_Matrix_size Size { get { return _size; } }
    }
}

namespace Row_Reduce_Algebra
{
    using Matrix_Algebra;
    public class TEST
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            C_Matrix_entries matrix_no1 = new C_Matrix_entries();
            for (int i = 0; i < matrix_no1.Size.size_R * matrix_no1.Size.size_C; i++)
            {
                // TODO: something useful
                Console.WriteLine(i); // FORNOW
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't access `matrix_no1.size` because `size` is inaccessible.

Add a public property to your `C_Matrix_entries` class, and reference it in `Main()`.

```
public class C_Matrix_entries
{
    public S_Matrix_size size { get; private set; }

    public C_Matrix_entries()
    {
        ...

        size = new S_Matrix_size(r,c);
```